# How to override Spring Social Security Sign in

Tags: java, spring, spring-social

I'm new to Java world and I'm trying to create a small project for school. Anyways, I'm stuck now. I followed https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-boot and now I have a simple facebook signup which is working and it creates a user record to database. Only email and name is inserted. I stripped off and modified code slightly.

Once the user registers user is signed in and security component works fine. Now the problem is that I'm not sure how to check whether user is already registered. I checked from the console for existing routes and found ProviderSignInController.java which controls the signin actions. There is also a method to handle sign in. But I'm not sure how to modify it. I've spent few hours on this. It doesn't even generate an error (which it should because it tries to fetch something from the table I do not have in SQL)

How should I move on?

Comment: If they have an account in the database, then they're already registered.  You should be checking their credentials (some OAuth value like a UID and provider) to see if they exist first.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Problem is that I do not know how to override the default logic.